# How do I click a button that has the same class as 10 others?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have a webpage that I'm trying to click a button on.
This is a couple of the webpage button codes:

```
<div class="ContentTab">My Bets</div>
<div class="ContentTab">Chat</div>
<div class="ContentTab">Account</div>
```

It only has the `innertext` different on them.

My goal was to click the "Chat" tab with this code, but it doesn't work.

```
foreach (HtmlElement chat in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
    if (chat.InnerText == "Chat")
    {
        chat.InvokeMember("Click");
        loggedIn = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that you are searching for "input" tags and have "div" tags in your html?

Comment: @JoelC This question benefits from the winforms tag as it defines the web browser control that is being used. Otherwise we might ask, what technology are you using?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I thought I had fixed it... I'll try that.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That was the problem... Thanks!

Comment: Converted to an answer since its not quite a "typographical error" Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for `input` tags with this code:

```
foreach (HtmlElement chat in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
```

But all your elements are declared as `div`:

```
<div class="ContentTab">My Bets</div>
<div class="ContentTab">Chat</div>
<div class="ContentTab">Account</div>
```

Making these consistent will fix your problem.

Comment: I know I set it right before, but my compiler crashed and so I lost it. I got another minor error, but I think I can get it fixed myself. Thanks a lot